# NXT Private blockchain changing the block generation time

Tags: nxt, ardor

By default the block time for nxt is 60 sec average this is question.

This parameter can be changed to a lower time 10 sec for e.g?

And if  yes what would be the possible impacts (negative and positives)

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the block time can be changed, but not very easy. There are two ways to do it:

1. Change the timestamp resolution to be 1/6th of the second. The
   drawback is that you will run out of int values 6 times sooner
   (timestamp is 32-bit integer). And eventually it will be less
   convenient to read timestamps.
2. Keep the timestamp resolution and
   adjust the forging. In Nxt there is no constant for changing the
   block time, so you'll have to change few other constants. A
   BLOCK_TIME constant was added in Ardor, you can see how it is used
   there. The drawbacks of having 10 sec blocktime with 1 sec
   resolution is that the base target adjustment will work not so well,
   so finally you may end up with average block time which is not
   10 sec.

A negative effect in both cases is that there will be less time for nodes to communicate new blocks and consequently more spontaneous forks will appear.
And the number of blocks will grow 6 times faster.

Comment: @Djalillounis, welcome, please accept my answer as best answer